# DateTime fields updates cause exception

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I've been using subsonic 3.0 for the past few days and ran into a problem. Using ActiveRecord and calling save on the existing record caused:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a char data type to a datetime
                            data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
                            The statement has been terminated.]
```

The code I'm using is just to demonstrate the problem:

```
public void ButtonCreate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    stPost post = new stPost();
    post.postCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    post.postDescription = "cool post at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    post.postGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    post.postTitle = "Post title";
    post.postUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

    post.Save();
}

public void ButtonUpdate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    stPost post = stPost.All().ToList<stPost>()[0];
    if (post != null && !post.IsNew()) {
        post.postDescription = "cool post UPDATED at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        post.postTitle = "Post title Updated";
        post.postUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        post.Save();
    }
}
```

Looking into sql profiler and resharper I found that insert and update statements are generated in completely different ways. On insert I'm getting the following sql code:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO 
 [dbo].[stPost]([dbo].[stPost].[postGuid],[dbo].[stPost].
 [postCreatedDate],[dbo].[stPost].[postUpdatedDate],[dbo].
 [stPost].[postTitle],[dbo].[stPost].[postDescription],[dbo].[stPost].[deleted])
VALUES
 (@ins_dbostPostpostGuid,@ins_dbostPostpostCreatedDate,
  @ins_dbostPostpostUpdatedDate,@ins_dbostPostpostTitle,
  @ins_dbostPostpostDescription,@ins_dbostPostdeleted);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as new_id;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as new_id',N'@ins_dbostPostpostGuid uniqueidentifier,
               @ins_dbostPostpostCreatedDate datetime,
               @ins_dbostPostpostUpdatedDate datetime,
               @ins_dbostPostpostTitle nvarchar(10),
               @ins_dbostPostpostDescription nvarchar(32),
               @ins_dbostPostdeleted bit',
               @ins_dbostPostpostGuid='91695935-588B-4617-8DB0-14210E97F718',
               @ins_dbostPostpostCreatedDate=''2009-07-14 14:11:52:997'',
               @ins_dbostPostpostUpdatedDate=''2009-07-14 14:11:52:997'',
               @ins_dbostPostpostTitle=N'Post title',
               @ins_dbostPostpostDescription=N'cool post at 14.07.2009 14:11:52',
               @ins_dbostPostdeleted=0
```

And on update

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [stPost] 
 SET postDescription=@up_postDescription, 
postTitle=@up_postTitle, 
postUpdatedDate=@up_postUpdatedDate
 WHERE [dbo].[stPost].[postID] =
 @0',N'@up_postDescription varchar(40),
 @up_postTitle varchar(18),
 @up_postUpdatedDate varchar(19),
 @0 int',
 @up_postDescription='cool post UPDATED at 14.07.2009 14:11:58',
 @up_postTitle='Post title Updated',
 @up_postUpdatedDate='14.07.2009 14:11:58',
 @0=2
```

On insert and update date is passed in the different ways. And parsing '14.07.2009' results in out-of-range value. I guess the problem might be somewhere in cultural/globalization settings because I have my local culture set to Russian, and sql server collation is set to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS. But the problem doesn't occure on insert, only on updates. And this makes me think that problem is somewhere in subsonic. 
Any help or ideas will be very appreciated.

Vladimir

Comment: Is this still an issue with 3.0.0.2?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you log this on our issues list and if possible give a unit test/schema I can repro with? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. I add an issue to github issues list on subsonic3 here 
http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/53